# Howto draw a empty rectangle in opengl?

Tags: c++11, opengl

Need draw a hollow rectangle in opengl and i try this using primitive objects:

```
void Skin::draw()
{
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.86, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(-0.7, -0.86, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(-0.7, -0.96, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.96, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(-0.8,  -0.86, 0); // XYZ left, top (close)

    glVertex3f(-0.79, -0.87, 0); // XYZ left, top (diagonal down-right)
    glVertex3f(-0.79, -0.95, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(-0.71, -0.95, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(-0.71, -0.87, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(-0.79, -0.87, 0); // XYZ left, top (close)

    glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.86, 0); // XYZ left, top (close diagonal top-left)

    glEnd();
}
```

But the result is a filled rectangle :(

Comment: But need set a custom weight of the line, they recommended me to use rectangles

Comment: In the future need make a round corners, i use poligons

Comment: This question is still unclear. Is it solved or is it deprecated? In former case you should answer it yourself, in later case you should delete it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw a rectangle with deprecated OpenGL fixed function pipeline then you can use [`glRect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRect.xm). But you have to change the polygon mode first. See [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml). The polygon mode defines, whether there are drawn points on the vertex coordinates (`GL_POINT`), lines between the vertex coordinates (`GL_LINE`) or the area enclosed by the primitive is filled (`GL_FILL`):

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
glRectf( -0.8, -0.96, -0.7, -0.86 );
glRectf( -0.79, -0.95, -0.71, -0.87 );
```

---

In general there are different types of [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) in OGL:

- Point primitives: `GL_POINTS`
- Line primitives: `GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_STRIP`, `GL_LINE_LOOP`
- Line primitives with adjacency information: `GL_LINES_ADJACENCY`, `GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY`
  Adjacencies do not create a further geometry, but the provide information which can be use in a geometry shader stage.
- Triangle primitives: `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`
- Triangle primitives with adjacency information: `GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP_ADJACENCY`
  Adjacencies do not create a further geometry, but the provide information which can be use in a geometry shader stage.

For the sickness of completeness there are, the list of **deprecated** primitive types: `GL_QUADS`, `GL_QUAD_STRIP`, and `GL_POLYGON`:

See further [Line primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives):

> There are 3 kinds of line primitives, based on different interpretations of a vertex stream.
>
> - `GL_LINES`: Vertices 0 and 1 are considered a line. Vertices 2 and 3 are considered a line. And so on. If the user specifies a non-even number of vertices, then the extra vertex is ignored.
> - `GL_LINE_STRIP`: The adjacent vertices are considered lines. Thus, if you pass n vertices, you will get n-1 lines. If the user only specifies 1 vertex, the drawing command is ignored.
> - `GL_LINE_LOOP`: As line strips, except that the first and last vertices are also used as a line. Thus, you get n lines for n input vertices. If the user only specifies 1 vertex, the drawing command is ignored. The line between the first and last vertices happens after all of the previous lines in the sequence.

This means, a rectangle can be drawn by a `GL_LINE_LOOP` with 4 vertices:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.86, 0); // XYZ left, top
glVertex3f(-0.7, -0.86, 0); // XYZ right, top
glVertex3f(-0.7, -0.96, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.96, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.79, -0.87, 0); // XYZ left, top
glVertex3f(-0.79, -0.95, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
glVertex3f(-0.71, -0.95, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
glVertex3f(-0.71, -0.87, 0); // XYZ right, top
glEnd();
```